# open jupyter notebook through cmd

Tags: python, jupyter

[image]

I open jupyter notebook through cmd, and I got this problem.
I don't know how to describe the problem ,maybe image is not enough.if need,please tell me what information is necessary!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `python -m ipykernel install --user` in cmd. Then relaunch jupyter.